# Distribution for $n$, the number of draws required to reach a target value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I draw with replacement from a pot containing 10 balls: 7 red, 3 white. If I draw a red ball I score 2 points, and if I draw a white ball I score 1 point. I stop drawing when I reach 10 or more points.

I am looking to find the distribution of $n$, the number of draws I make before stopping.

I can use brute force to define and sample from this distribution without issue. But I am having trouble defining a closed form mathematical solution.

I'm guessing the distribution will be related to the binomial distribution since it is discrete and we are sampling with replacement. However although we have a defined trial success probability (e.g 7/10 = 0.7), I'm looking to find the number of trials, $n$, which is variable and not the number of successes (although this value would be related to the number of trials needed to reach 10)

Is there a family of discrete distributions that fits this type of problem or would this require some kind of compound distribution?

Comment: Have you tried to write down some combination of 1 and 2 where the sum is $10$ or $11$. For instance, drawing 4 times a red ball, once a white ball and at last a red ball the combination is $21222|2$. And from $21222$ we can get $\binom{5}{1}$ permutations.

Comment: I can write down all the possible permutations for each number of draws from the minimum, 5, to the maximum, 10 like you say. So yes,  doing this is a closed form solution giving me the exact answer. But it isn't practical if I were to extend the problem to a much larger finishing score as the number of permutations gets unmanageable by hand. Just like I can use the binomial distribution to find the distribution of red balls drawn from 10 (or any number of) draws, is there a related distribution that neatly gives the distribution in this problem?